# ImageView Button hides textbox and images ANDROID

Tags: android, imageview

how can i make it where a ImageView button when you click it, it will hide 2 pictures and a text box?

then when i click a different image view it will show them again

here's my code (not added any thing)

http://pastebin.com/XTrAy8sX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the onClickListener for the ImageView, you can use setVisibility() to change the visibility of the other two views

Comment: Can you give me a example on how i can do it?

Comment: eg in the onClick() you would put
findViewById(R.id.image1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Thank you it worked!! How can i do it where it changes the text in a textbox

Comment: same sort of thing, ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(string)